# Linux filepath setting and executing C program

Tags: linux, gcc, filepath

I am a beginner in programming. I have downloaded C library code for mqtt client into my system (Fedora). It has three folders; `bin`, `include` and `lib`.

I wrote a `main.c`. Where should I keep this `main.c`? Outside these folders? Do I need to set file path? I tried to execute using gcc it is showing file not found.

Comment: Put your code wherever you want, just set the proper inclusion directories when you compile and library directories when you link.

Comment: Look at the `-I`, `-l` and `-L` options of (I assume gcc)